# Alter style on Menu Item(s) when Menu Type Type used is Alias in Administrator Template

Tags: menu-item, seo

When creating an Alias to a single article, the content editors keep making this mistake where they select an Alias which has the same/similar title to the 'Single Article' Menu item.

When an alias is pointing to an Alias, this causes a broken link since as alias can't be pointing to another alias.

Is there any way to not display aliases when the 'Menu Item Type' being created/updated itself is an alias?

Or at the very least, is there a way to alter the CSS so that if there is two Menu Items being displayed with the same 'Title', the alias or the menu item gets highlighted so that it is obvious which is alias and which is a single article?

Comment: What do you mean 'Alias is pointing to an Alias'? How do you make it?

Comment: Let's say you have a menu called books with a single article item 'New Books'. Now there is another menu called top navigation which has a menu item alias again with the exact same title 'New Books'. Up until this it works fine since the alias is pointing to the correct single article menu item.  Now add another menu that also needs a link to New Books. This is also a menu item alias but when you search for the 'New Cars' single article menu item, both the single article and the alias item are displayed with no distinguishing feature that one of those Iran alias!!!

Comment: "...Now there is another menu called top navigation which has a menu item alias again with the exact same title 'New Books'..." At this point I have the following warning: `Save failed with the following error: Another menu item has the same alias in Root. Root is the top level parent.` Actually, this should be titled 'Error', not 'Warning'. Is your menu 'Top navigation' a sub-menu of the previous one?

Comment: Please see my answer to Nehal..

Answer (score 2):

You can never save 2 menu items with alias. You will always get this message:
**Save failed with the following error: Another menu item has the same alias in Root. Root is the top level parent.**

Yes this can happen that your menu item alias and article item alias is same.

Are you creating a New Menu with *Menu type* as **Menu Item Alias** ?

Please if you can explain briefly your issue or add screenshots for this ?

Comment: The issue is not duplicate alias. The issue is when I am creating a menu item alias which auto generates the alias, sometimes this new alias is pointed to another alias which causes the link to be something like this: /ItemId=197. So my question which I guess I was not clear enough on was that is there any way to distinguish a menu item alias from a single item article menu type when I am creating a menu item alias? Will post some screenshots in a bit to make it more clear.

Comment: Here is the screenshot.
[ [Screenshot](http://i.imgur.com/1YQ5Lt3.png "Alias") ]

As you can see there can be 3 Menus with a child 'New Books' (like /fiction/new-books). My question is since any of those could be an alias, is there a way to distinguish an alias in the 'Menu Item' dropdown from a Single Article Menu Item when creating an alias Menu Item like I am doing here.

Comment: Ok got your problem, I guess in the list ( drop down) that appears, you need menu items to be differentiated that which menu is linked with `'Single Article'` and which is `'Menu item alias'` from those 3 menu.

Please let me know, what I understood is correct or not ?

Comment: yes you are correct!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it looks like there is a small bug in Joomla. 
You should not be offered any 'Menu Item Aliases' in `Menu Item` drop-down box when `Menu item type` is 'Menu Item Alias'.
It is not exactly bug, but something which could cause inconvenience.

Comment: I think it is an expected behaviour but it is much more than an inconvenience when content editors are making the same mistake again and again causing broken links way too often. Looks like the CSS option is out of the table as there seems to be no distinguishing classes when an alias is loaded instead of a single article in the drop down.